# Range for vector values in gensim model

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am extracting the word embeddings vector from a word2vec model using model.wv. What is the range of values for each element in this vector?

```
import gensim

word2vec_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("testModel")
word2vec_model.wv["increase"] #What is range of values for each vector element?
```

Can't seem to find this information in the documentation.

Comment: Please give us the complete context and a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every dimension of the vector is 32-bit floating point value.

There's no essential or enforced limit other than that, though the training process is such that individual dimensions tend not to be "very large" – often staying in the range between -1.0 and 1.0.

It's common (but not required or beneficial for all applications) to normalize word-vectors to have a magnitude of 1.0 before comparing them to other similarly-normalized word-vectors.

You can request such a unit-normalized version of a word-vector with the `word_vec()` method's `use_norm` parameter:

```
model.wv.word_vec(word, use_norm=True)
```

In such a unit-normed vector, no single dimension will be outside the range of -1.0 to 1.0.